# Parameter with nested array - is iteration possible?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Is it possible to use nested arrays in Properties? Assuming top array would be a parent resource and nested array are child resources for each parent. I would like then to iterate all parents and then all childs associated for each parent.

Here's an example ARM Template. Where I'm creating a ServiceBus with Topics and Subscriptions. Each topic would have at least one subscription associated with it. It would be the easiest to define properties for Topics - Subscriptions in a nested arrays, like in example below.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "defaultValue": {
        "location": "uksouth",
        "name": "myNewSB1",
        "skuCapacity": 1,
        "skuName": "Standard",
        "skuTier": "Standard"
      },
      "type": "object"
    },
    "serviceBusTopics": {
      "defaultValue": [
        {
          "name": "topic1",
          "subscriptions": [
            "topic1-sub1",
            "topic1-sub2"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "topic2",
          "subscriptions": [
            "topic2-subAbc"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "topicOther",
          "subscriptions": [
            "topicOther-subDef1",
            "topicOther-subDef2",
            "topicOther-subDef3",
            "topicOther-subDef4"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "type": "array"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
      "location": "[parameters('serviceBus').location]",
      "name": "[parameters('serviceBus').name]",
      "sku": {
        "capacity": "[parameters('serviceBus').skuCapacity]",
        "name": "[parameters('serviceBus').skuName]",
        "tier": "[parameters('serviceBus').skuTier]"
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces"
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
      "copy": {
        "count": "[length(parameters('serviceBusTopics'))]",
        "mode": "Parallel",
        "name": "topicsLoop"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', parameters('serviceBus').name)]"
      ],
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBus').name, '/', parameters('serviceBusTopics')[copyIndex()].name)]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics"
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
      "copy": {
        "count": "[length(<...>)]",
        "mode": "Parallel",
        "name": "subscriptionsLoop"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "topicsLoop"
      ],
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBus').name, '/', <...>, '/', <...>)]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you have 2 options:

1. Hardcode each resource, so create 1 resource for 1 object in the array and that way you will be able to iterate, but when you add\remove objects from the array - you will need to adjust the template (not optimal, obviously)
2. Use a nested template. Let me elaborate a bit:

`not sure how to reset the list counter, lol`

1. Create a nested deployment in the template that iterates the base array so `serviceBusTopics`
2. pass current iteration to the nested template: `"[parameters('serviceBusTopics')[copyIndex()]]"`
3. in the nested template you are only dealing with a single object that has one of the properties of type array and you can iterate that.

Comment: This is what I‘ve suspected - nested arrays in params are not supported for iteration. I’ve already solved this problem similarly to option 1. from your response.

Comment: It’s easier to manage topics-subscription relations in params. In the end I’ve used this approach: https://rjayapal.com/2018/04/30/azure-arm-templates-nested-loops-possible-workaround-copy-loop/?fbclid=IwAR3FnDPxX_r-59yMfI8jxQfY4EkkZRchhQRWCLiyEyLKSYSyWBHaYhN3n6o

Comment: nah, not really. this way you duplicate data and its very error prone